# Generate Signing Link through API

Tags: docusignapi

Currently using DocuSign-Powerform which generates signing link to recipient. I need to know if signing link can be generated by envelope ID through **DocuSign API** for specific project requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the API to generate a link that can be used to initiate the recipient signing session, the envelope must have been created via the API in the first place. (In the API documentation, this scenario -- creating the envelope via API and then subsequently using the API to generate the link that can be used to initiate the recipient signing session -- is referred to as "embedded" signing or "captive" signing.)

If you're creating the envelope via any other means (e.g., Powerforms or the DocuSign web UI), it's not possible to use the API to generate a link that can be used to initiate the recipient signing session.